# Неповторимый: какая часть речи?

Tags: словообразование, части-речи

*Это были неповторимые эмоции.*

К какой части речи можно отнести "неповторимые": относительное/качественное прилагательное, причастие?
Можно ли употреблять степени сравнения?
От какой части речи образовано слово?

Answer (score 1):

Это, как уже правильно заметил Игорь, качественное прилагательное. Степени сравнения с ним не употребляются: не может быть более неповторимого и т. п.

Answer (score 0):

Это качественное прилагательное, образованное от глагола "повторить" с отрицательной частицей "не".